# Access DLNA TV with Java code

Tags: java, dlna

I want to control my DLNA TV from my Java program on my PC. In particular, I want to:

- discover if there's a TV in the LAN
- check whether it is currently ON (for a first step)
- later send some commands (eg. OFF) to it

I believe, I need to implement the Digital Media Controller (DLNA-DMC) profile. Is there a Java library which allows me to do this easily?

I couldn't find much doc on this. Are the APIs under NDA?

Can you recommend some reading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Cling](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/). I'm not sure it implements the [UPnP control point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#Other_components) features you're in fact looking for, but at least it's a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

[ohNet](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) does exactly what you want.

It is available under BSD license and includes the control point stack you need and can generate code to greatly simplify use of the services in any profile (see the docs on ohNetGen).

(Disclaimer: I have contributed to this project)

Answer (score 2):

Intel DLNA tools allows you to create DLNA control point very easily for any platform in any language c,c++, C#, Java.
Try [Intel® Software for UPnP* Technology: Download Tools](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-for-upnp-technology-download-tools/)

They even have tools to test you app.

Comment: Looks like .NET instead of Java.

Comment: Old links. There's nothing there.